# what literally defines a django app?

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I have read a few questions about what an "app" is supposed to mean in django, but they go into the general purpose/use of an app, which is important, but not what an app literally "is". For example, I felt my curiosity today when

1. I deleted a folder that I installed as an app with django-admin startapp, and received a certain error that stackO told me was due to a deleted app name residing in my INSTALLED_APPS. After clearing the name, my app worked again
2. When making a folder cold (just mkdir, no startapp) in the highest level of a project, when trying to import names from real apps, I have to add my project to the sys.path list to be able to import. After remaking this folder as an app, imports are no longer an issue

I've read questions about this topic that had comments like "OK, I've got a models.py file, so it's an app", and it seems like very few people really understand how an app is started.

My question is,

1. what leeway do I have to modify the apps django makes? Can I delete all the files that come with it (except init) and make it a cold library with no views and models? Are any files besides **init** required to function correctly?
2. What does django do when I run startapp that causes an app to be importable automatically, which effect is not there when I make a folder with an **init** in it (as I said about needing to add the project path to sys.path within that folder). In other words, what does the django command "startapp" actually do to register an app? The action is in django.core.management.templates.py, I read it today and saw things in TemplateCommand.handle() that refer to app or project names, but couldn't see exactly how it registers them. It imports sys, but searching "sys.module" isn't in the file
3. If I want to turn an empty directory with **init** into an app, what do I have to do in the shell to make this change without doing startapp?

Thank you

Comment: `validate_name` is a simple method that checks the given argument starts with a letter/underscore and only contains letters/numbers/underscores. It will raise an error if not. It does nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR: Django apps are just Python packages within your project, and you don't need any file except for `__init__.py` to import it.**

I also experienced this vague explanation of "app" from the Django docs, and it led me to look into what a "web app" in the general scheme was before I could understand the concept of a Django one when I was starting out.

Generally defined, a web application is any program transferred from server to client via a browser. This could be an entire website, a certain component in a website (think captchas, widgets, OAuth, etc.), or a function of a website (such as integration with other technologies, like exporting a page to a PDF). These can be modular components or not, portable or not, and distinct within the project's source code or mixed with other things.

Since the general "web app" definition is quite ambiguous, it may be easier to imagine the "Django app." Your project contains one or more apps, of which some may have files or not. **Technically,** your app can contain nothing except the `__init__.py` and still be imported (it's just a normal Python package, albeit a useless one). You **can** make it a library with other modules, but this seems unpythonic, and I make a point to separate business logic from my website source code whenever possible.

Apps are simply things that do something for your project. A question that many people, including myself, like to ask to define an app, is "what does it do?" If you can't answer this question in a concise manner (that doesn't include "and") then your app could be broken into several different parts. This is recommended for your sake, but you may break this rule if you really want. In my first Django project, I made the entire website inside one app folder. It became a nightmare to manage, but I did it.

Views and models are just places to store the information that you need to use for that app in one place; if there was just one big app for your entire website, things would get cluttered and unmanageable very quickly. That would certainly be unpythonic, and the Django developers are very conscious of making things "correctly."

As for technical specifics, Django projects are packages. You can play around with manage.py startproject and checking your sys.path before/after. Apps are packages as well, which (supposedly) contain modules that allow your "app" to perform its intended function. You can use them for anything, everything, or nothing at all, but they are just a Python package with modules in a neat little folder on your system to do something for your project.

You can find a quick overview of applications in the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/), if you haven't already. Also, this is all a product of my base understanding, so if there is any problem with any part of my answer, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, that's very close, but only missing #2- I edited the question to be more clear

Comment: For #2, django does not do anything special. The startapp command will just interpolate the app template (you can find it in django/conf/app_template) and write the result into your project. Though depending on your Django version, an empty module might not be enough (up to Django 1.7 you need a models.py file as well).

Comment: The validate_name() function (defined in django.core.management.templates), as @spectras said, simply checks to make sure the name is valid (it does a regex check to see if it's letters and underscores and raises an error if not). Apps are automatically importable due to the fact that, when created, the startapp command does a few checks and then calls the handle() command of the TemplateCommand class defined in the same module as validate_name(), which then adds the specified directory to the path (in Django 1.8.2, it's in line 82 of the module).

Comment: @spectras, so if I make an empty directory in the project level, I can make an __init__ and models file, and register it as an app in settings and it's good?

Comment: "Technically, your app can contain nothing except the init.py and still be imported (it's just a normal Python package, albeit a useless one)."

Actually, I tried that, to make it without using "startapp", and it didn't work

Comment: In Django 1.8.2, I just created a new folder within my project that contained only an `__init__.py` module, and was able to successfully import it from an interactive session as well as include it in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings and have the server start. As @spectras noted, if you're using below version 1.7 you need a models.py. If so, what are you trying to do? Your app has no functions with just an `__init__.py` and so I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: @codyc4321 yeah it's good. It's empty though so you won't see anything. Even the admin will skip empty apps.